# d3.js multi bar does not refresh

Tags: d3.js

My d3 multi bar does not refresh after data changes. If there is more bars it add it in the end of old but does not remove old ones. If there is less bars it does not add it at all. Axis changes all the time for that from new data

```
        var bars = svg.select(".chart-group")
            .selectAll(".state")
            .data(data);

        bars.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "state")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + x0Scale(d[KEY]) + ",0)";
            });
        bars.exit().remove();
        bars.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function (d) {
                return d.ages;
            })
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("width", x1Scale.rangeBand())
            .attr("x", function (d) {
                return x1Scale(d[SEGMENT]);
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                return yScale(d[DATA]);
            })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
                return chartH - yScale(d[DATA]);
            })
            .style("fill", function (d) {
                return color(d[SEGMENT]);
            });
```

**Edit:**
Here is fiddle with my problem https://jsfiddle.net/wxw5zdws/

I achieve my goal when whole container is removed:

```
        if (container) {
            container.remove();
        }
```

I think it is bad practice, there is an issue in my drawing bars method. It should use old elements and remove/add usseless/needed elements.

What is wrong with this bars?

Comment: Could you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Edit:: fiddle example od my problem

Comment: It looks like you're appending new elements when updating regardless of what's already there. You need to handle the update and exit selections as well, see e.g. http://bost.ocks.org/mike/circles